# extract data from reponse typed json data using Regular Expression Extractor in jmeter

Tags: regex, json, jmeter

I want to extract data from response in jmeter, the response data is

```
{
   "id" : {
    "idUri" : [ "/id/123123" ]
   }
}
```

And I use Regular Expression Extractor to extract the string `/id/123123`.
My configuration of Regular Expression Extractor is

```
Reference Name: id
Regular Expression: "idUri" : [ "(.+?)" ]
Template: $1$
Match No.(0 for Random): 1
Default Value: failed_id
```

But when I use the id, I always got `failed_id`.
How should I set the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression (updated as per rsp comment):

```
Regular Expression: "idUri" : \[ "([^"]+?)" \]
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it does'n work. I think it is the problem of slash matching. "idUri" : (.+?), I can get the character [. But when I use "idUri" : [ "(.+?)" ], it failed. Could you tell me how should I do, thanks.

Comment: @user2256235, you should escape the special characters in your regexp, like so `"idUri" : \[ "([^"]+?)" \]`

Comment: I modified, if answer is OK (I think it is) , you should accept it and upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can update your regular expression in the following format to get your id values

```
Reference Name: id
Regular Expression: idUri"\s:\s\[\s"/id/(.+)"
Template: $1$
Match No.(0 for Random): 1
Default Value: failed_id
```

Note:

```
\s - means single space
```